# What does "uss-en uthers" mean?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

> Big Boss Nass: Who's da **uss-en uthers**?
>
> Queen: I am Queen Amidala of the Naboo. I come before you in peace.
>
> Big Boss Nass: Naboo biggen. Yousa bringen da Mackineeks. Yousa all
> bombad.

What does "uss-en uthers" mean?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO "uss-en uthers" means "youse others" which is slang for "you others", referring to other people in the group who have arrived.  Presumably some people already introduced themselves and Boss Nass was asking who the unintroduced people were.

Comment: In this case, Nass knew Jar-Jar and had already met Jinn and Kenobi, so no prior introduction in this scene was necessary.